# Installing older Android SDK using Homebrew

Tags: android, macos, homebrew, android-sdk-2.1

I am trying to install Android SDK version 21

```
android-sdk git:(master) ✗ brew versions android-sdk 
Warning: brew-versions is unsupported and will be removed soon.
You should use the homebrew-versions tap instead:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions

24.1.2   git checkout bd7fe0a /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
24.0.2   git checkout 9bae1ec /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
24.0.1   git checkout dfc52fa /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
24       git checkout 9c59883 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
23.0.2   git checkout 40a85ed /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
23.0.1   git checkout dafcd64 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
23       git checkout fc9b23b /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
22.6.2   git checkout b40ef74 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
22.6     git checkout 21a3ec9 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
22.3     git checkout 05c8367 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
22.2.1   git checkout a8e49e1 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
22.2     git checkout 65aa6b0 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
22.0.5   git checkout 1b2c080 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
r22.0.4  git checkout 758cbf0 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
r22.0.1  git checkout 33258e5 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
r21.1    git checkout c150b7e /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
r21.0.1  git checkout 5909091 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
r21      git checkout 276fd63 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
r20.0.3  git checkout 1d90e9d /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
```

Then to install version 21

```
git checkout  276fd63 /usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
android-sdk git:(master) ✗ brew install  android-sdk
```

But I get the following error

```
 ==> Downloading http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r21-macosx.zip
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/android-sdk-r21.zip
Error: wrong number of arguments (0 for 3)
Please report this bug:
https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:86:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb:55:in `new'
/usr/local/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb:55:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:136:in `block in install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:410:in `block in brew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:766:in `block in stage'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:91:in `block in unpack'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/fileutils.rb:17:in `mktemp'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:88:in `unpack'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:81:in `stage'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:764:in `stage'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:406:in `brew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:114:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:186:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I have got the same problem